# Selecting gate driver for smps

Tags: power-supply, pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, gate-driving

I'm trying to design and build a smps that has a 120VAC input with a 5VDC (2 Amp) output and this is what I have designed for it so far. I was thinking of having a pic18f4685 to do the pwm to drive the gate of my mosfet. According to my simulation results I need 18V ~42% Duty Cycle at 400KHz in order to have the buck converter work correctly. I'm having trouble picking out a gate driver that works with my design. Can anyone recommend a through hole ic that I can use on a breadboard to test out? Is there any ic's that do feedback also so that I can possibly eliminate using a pic chip? I can't buy a complete buck converter ic for my project and it has to be custom. Just trying to build the easier smps possible without buying an ic that does everything! I appreciate all the input. If you have some schematic of a simple buck converter laying around that isn't just an ic please share it.[image]

Comment: I have found the si823x line to perform well in this regard. Only soic packaged, but you can get soic to dip adapters.

Comment: Why are you still using an NMOS while it would make things so much less complex if you just used a PMOS ? This was already suggested in one of your other questions.

Comment: "it has to be custom." so, then it's a homework exercise or something?

Answer (score 1):

I searched "nmos high side driver dip" on google and found a number. The IRS2117PBF should work well. Also check out the other chips from that [google search](https://www.google.com/search?output=search&tbm=shop&q=nmos+high+side+driver+dip&oq=nmos+high+side+driver+dip&gs_l=products-cc.3...1286.1286.0.1463.1.1.0.0.0.0.65.65.1.1.0....0...1ac.1.64.products-cc..1.0.0.KWbtol55emk&gws_rd=ssl).

In terms of using an IC with feedback, I'll need more details about the limitations of your project to give a good answer. If custom means that you need to design the basic buck circuit by hand, you can get buck controller ICs that don't include the switch. For example, you could use a [LM3489](https://www.ti.com/product/lm3489). It includes the feedback and gate driver circuitry. You'd implement it like so and just have to add a couple components to what you have so far to get it working...
[image: LM3489 Circuit]

Comment: If I used the LM3489 I would have to change to a pmos. Can I just pick any and it should work?

Comment: yup, switching to a pmos should't be hard just make sure it meets the Vds and current requirements. You can also use a nmos driver. I did a quick search and found the [lm5088](http://www.ti.com/product/lm5088?qgpn=lm5088). It has to boost up to drive the nmos gate so there are some extra components in the circuit, but just use the circuit in the datasheet and you should be good. Personally, I'd switch to pmos because circuit is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your output current,it is only 2Amps. Also your simulated duty cycle is 42%. The peak current would be twice the output current in circuit or transition or S TRAP mode. Orthodox current mode pwm would give a peak current of perhaps 3 Amp depending on frequency and Inductance Value. OK the mosfet won't have to be huge, so it wont have too much gate capacitance, it can be cheap. In fact you can use a P channel device using simple discrete components instead of a gold plated driver chip. Suggestion NTD2955. Don,t be shy about the package because you should be able to use the micro to do a better switching regime than current mode PWM aka 1960s.